# How can I integrate an external assembly as a resource into a .net executable

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, shared-libraries

I have an application that makes use of/consumes services from a number of external .net libraries, which in turn calls certain executables. Would it be possible to integrate these into one huge executable and load them from my application to the disk as required? Resources come to mind but not sure how that is done.

Thanks,

Comment: The usual name for a program like this is *setup.exe*.  Trivial to create with a Setup project.  Also solves the chicken-and-egg problem of embedding the .NET framework into your exe so it runs on old versions of Windows.

Comment: Certainly not what I am looking for, clickOnce deployment already helps with deploying the required assemblies to a target system. The below answer provided by Espen and others below is my answer, embedding the actual consumed assembly into the main executable of the program. Even better the link Espen provides below has a link to ILMerge from Microsoft which is an even simpler method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx) to merge all your assemblies into a single executable file.

Answer (score 3):

You have several options to do that:

- use [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17630) (free)
  For howto see [here](https://github.com/Tigraine/dotless/blob/master/default.ps1#L87) and [here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx)

OR

- use some tool like [SmartAssembly](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/smartassembly/) (commercial)
  it can embed and merge among other things (no need to change your source code)

OR

- [code that yourself in less than 10 lines](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx) (free but minimal source code change)
  mark all needed dependencies as "embedded resource" - this way they are included in the EXE file... you need to setup an [`AssemblyResolve`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) handler which at runtime reads from Resources and returns the needed DLLs to the .NET runtime...

Answer (score 1):

You can find a complete example at [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/EmbedAssemblyAsResource.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Espen, also came across ILMerge on that link which is provided by Microsoft.